# std::exchange default template parameter specification

Tags: c++

I would like to understand motivation for why the template parameter `U` is defaulted to `T` below, i.e. when is it not deduced from the function argument?

```cpp
template<class T, class U = T>
  constexpr T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_val)
{
    T old_val = std::move(obj);
    obj = std::forward<U>(new_val);
    return old_val;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Paper [N3668](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3668)
motivates the default value for the second template argument with these
two examples:

```cpp
// (1)
DefaultConstructible x = ...;
if (exchange(x, {})) { ... }
```

```cpp
// (2)
int (*fp)(int);
int f(int);
double f(double);
/*...*/ exchange(fp, &f) /*...*/
```

So, basically, it's for convenience. The advantage in the above examples is:

1. Allow passing a default-constructed `DefaultConstructible` as `new_val` without having to spell its type name;
2. Making a cast of `&f` to `int (*)(int)` unnecessary.